# EntityFramework Sync Context with Sql Server Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, synchronization, dbcontext

i am currently developing a multi user wpf application. 
First of all i wanna give you a short overview about the system.
Each client loads the full data from a sql server database. Each client can create and modify data which belongs to him. Data from other clients cannot be modified.
What i wanna do now is, sync my (long living -> context lives as long as the MainWindow is running) dbcontext, means when other clients write / update data in the database this data should be synced to each dbcontext, means each client can see the data of all other clients but is not allowed to modify / delete them (each record contains user field)

Now the big question is, how can i achieve the sync of the long-living dbcontext?
Is there any kind of sync framework (i have found the microsoft sync framework, but i think this solution does not fit for my problem.) I am looking for a method to sync the full dbcontext (all entities). Do i need to write my own sync, like polling the db?

Ok, i found a way to refresh all entities that were loaded first within the dbcontext using this lines of code:

```
 var refreshableObjects = Remoting.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(c => c.Entity).ToList();
        Remoting.Context.ObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
```

Now this only refreshes already existing entities. No the other thing is,
how can i get all new added records in the database and add them to my context.
Is there a way to reexecute my linq query and merge the results?

I am using Entityframework code first approach.

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: "context lives as long as the MainWindow is running" is a wrong decision.

Comment: You do not have to 'sync' DbContexts. You just have to query fresh data when needed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman why is it wrong to have a long living context per window? I am working on this data and need to save it to the database.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i dont know when a different user adds new entities to the database, therefore i thought there would be a smart sync mechanism that keeps the entities and the database in sync.